# Return Rows as per Quantity of Columns Value In SQL

Tags: sql, database, sql-server-2008

I have data in a table like below.

[image]

Now I want to return rows as per the values of the Quantity column.

Like above data row 1 have the **Quantity 4** then in output of select query there will be **4** rows for row 1, similar to for row 2 quantity is 8 then there will be 8 rows.

When I have write query on above data then it should return 26 rows.

Comment: You probably have a normalization problem if you have to perform such a query. I suggest you or a db administrator take a look at the structure of the tables.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Query:

**[SQLFIDDLEExample](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/2af2c/3)**

```
SELECT tbl.*
FROM tbl, 
    (SELECT number
    FROM master..spt_values 
    WHERE Type = 'P') n
WHERE tbl.Quantity > n.number
```

Result:

```
| ROWNO | QUANTITY | SIZE |
|-------|----------|------|
|     1 |        4 |  YXS |
|     1 |        4 |  YXS |
|     1 |        4 |  YXS |
|     1 |        4 |  YXS |
|     2 |        8 |  2XL |
|     2 |        8 |  2XL |
|     2 |        8 |  2XL |
|     2 |        8 |  2XL |
|     2 |        8 |  2XL |
|     2 |        8 |  2XL |
|     2 |        8 |  2XL |
|     2 |        8 |  2XL |
|     3 |        7 |   XL |
|     3 |        7 |   XL |
|     3 |        7 |   XL |
|     3 |        7 |   XL |
|     3 |        7 |   XL |
|     3 |        7 |   XL |
|     3 |        7 |   XL |
|     4 |        7 |  YXS |
|     4 |        7 |  YXS |
|     4 |        7 |  YXS |
|     4 |        7 |  YXS |
|     4 |        7 |  YXS |
|     4 |        7 |  YXS |
|     4 |        7 |  YXS |
```

**Explanation:**

Column `number` from table `spt_values` contains continuous values from 0 to 2047 for `Type` 'P'.

These values are joined in, leading to 2048 duplicates returned for each record, and then restricted to return only the number of `Quantity` via the `WHERE`clause.